# How can I template message in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

For example I have message with `{{hello}} world!` with value `hello = Hola` how can I make it? I understand we can have `<tag>{{hello}}</tag>` to get the tag value but what if I want to use template message?

What I really want is something like

```
<tag
  :message=`{{hello}} world!`
  :hello="hola"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this method.

```
<tag
  :message="`${hello} world!`"
  :hello="hello"
/>
data(){
  return{
    hello:'hora'
  }
}
```